# WebRTC to PSTN call established but no audio

Tags: javascript, webrtc, asterisk, sip, sipml

Basically i set up an asterisk server, connected to a sip provider to make calls to pstn or mobile networks. I have configured SIP to SIP properly because when i make calls from softphone e.g. Zoiper - Asterisk - Sip provider - Mobile network, the call is established and i can hear audio on both ends.

I want to use WebRTC so im using sipML5 as a client on localhost.
I registered sip peer on sipml5 it works fine. I make a call to the softphone or to the PSTN/Mobile network and the call is established but no audio on both ends.

sipML5 gives me an error: onSetRemoteDescriptionError

DOMException: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called with SDP without ice-ufrag and ice-pwd.

I have enabled ice in rtp.conf and also in the peers in sip.conf. Also put google stun server in rtp.conf.

I can't figure out what the problem is. The problem is in WebRTC to SIP. 
I haven't installed webrtc2sip gateway by doubango. i am not sure if i should install it since im using asterisk 13.

Any idea what might the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just posting the answer to this for anyone that might need it in the future. 
Basically i was working on localhost without https, for WebRTC is mandatory having https, and in order to make the calls i enabled rtc breaker which lets you make calls even if it is not https connection. So after i just made the connection https, disabled rtc breaker and now everything works as expected. Audio is produced imediately after picking up the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you don't have the necessary packages on your system to support ICE in Asterisk. There's a thread in the old Asterisk forums that talks about debugging this issue [here](http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90167).

The gist is that you need `uuid-devel` & `libuuid-devel` installed on your system prior to compiling Asterisk, so that it compiles with ICE support. Then run the configure script prior to running `make` to ensure that it picks up the new packages.

Comment: Already did, i made it work by just leaving asterisk out of this and installed webrtc2sip, created self signed certificate and it is fine, only delay on audio after call is established